# CLion fails to index C preprocessor macros when -std=gnuXX is set (Linux Kernel Headers)

Tags: c, linux-kernel, c-preprocessor, code-completion, clion

I am trying to write a Linux kernel module with CLion. This is the cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(labs)

set(KERNEL_HEADERS
        /home/alex/Developer/linux/include
        /home/alex/Developer/linux/arch/x86/include
        /home/alex/Developer/linux/arch/x86/include/generated
        /home/alex/Developer/linux/include/uapi
        /home/alex/Developer/linux/include/generated/uapi
        /home/alex/Developer/linux/arch/x86/include/uapi
        /home/alex/Developer/linux/arch/x86/include/generated/uapi
)

set(MY_MODULE_SOURCES
    chapter_03/lab_01/hello.c
)

add_definitions(-imacros /home/alex/Developer/linux/include/linux/kconfig.h)
add_definitions(-D__KERNEL__)
add_definitions(-DMODULE)
add_definitions(-std=gnu89)
include_directories(${KERNEL_HEADERS})


add_custom_target(labs COMMAND $(MAKE) -C ${labs_SOURCE_DIR}
                         PWD=${labs_SOURCE_DIR})

add_library(dummylib ${MY_MODULE_SOURCES})
```

The actual building of the kernel module is done with the externally called makefile using "add_custom_target". The "dummylib" is only there so that CLion actually starts to parse the header files and gives me auto completion. With my supplied definitions it does even compile the "dummylib" successfully (look at the screenshot). It is no kernel module though, but that does not matter ;)

[image: CLion failing to index macros]

My problem is the error you see in the screenshot. Somehow it says that it can't resolve all the macros defined in the kernel headers. Functions, structs and plain defines ( "MODULE_SIG_STRING ") do work (as you see). I do not understand why the editor says it cannot resolve the macro but can still build it. What is more strange is that I can even jump to the declaration using STRG+B of the marked macros. Clearly something is going wrong. The macros are really defined within [linux/module.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/module.h).

### Update

When I set -std=c89 instead of -std=gnu89 the editor recognizes the macros but the "dummylib" of course fails to build since the kernel needs the gnu extensions. I guess this is a bug in CLion. I posted it at the Jetbrains Bugtracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6875

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue but like you I haven't found a full solution yet. Your workaround seems to be the best way to somewhat mitigate this until we have a proper solution by JB, thank you.

Comment: CPP-6875 is closed and marked Fixed. Did that fix it for you? I'm having a similar issue with CLION 2018.2 but using the new compiler database function instead of CMake.